# Not Authorized for dynamodb:PutItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

Hi when I try to send a request to my lambda function and store data in dynamodb, I get the following error. The project is built with the serverless framework.

Error Message: **User: is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/${self:service}-OrdersTable-${sls:stage}**

serverless.yml

```yaml
iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:PutItem
            - dynamodb:GetItem
          Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/{self:service}-OrdersTable-${sls:stage}
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - kinesis:PutRecord
          Resource: arn:aws:kinesis:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:stream/{self:service}-OrderStream-${sls:stage}
```

Answer (score 0):

Role statements looks fine. Check if you set this role properly for your functions...
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam

Or try setting iamRoleStatements directly for the function to check if permission part is working fine. Here is an example for that
https://medium.com/@glicht/serverless-framework-defining-per-function-iam-roles-c678fa09f46d